# Should I replace all of my unidimensional arrays to sets?

Tags: python, arrays, list, performance, optimization

Since dicts more performant than regular arrays, should I replace an array with a set(dict) when I can? (In cases where I just loop though the array, without splicing it or anything)

Comment: I imagine the answer to your question is - *it depends...*.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092)

Comment: that depends (see first comment) on how you are using them... in you just iterate then `list`s are perfectly fine. for membership tests `set`s are more efficient... etc.

Comment: How do you define *array*?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think dicts or sets are faster than arrays (you mean `list` or `array.array`?). The reason is that when accessing array items you basically know immediately where the item is going to be in memory, whereas with dict you have to compute (and possibly try few different memory locations) the location.

In other words, arrays are much more simple than dicts or sets and are therefore faster.

When your benchmark says otherwise, perhaps you are not benchmarking item access. Perhaps your benchmark ran too shortly?

PS: To be precise, there are cases where dict/set is faster than array but I assume that situation is not your case. When you have a huge *sparse* array and you access it randomly it can happen that the cache hierarchy of you computer imposes greater cost that having tiny dict/set fitting in the fastest cache layer.

Comment: The correct answer is "it depends". Arrays are faster for some purposes, but slower for others.

Answer (score 0):

As @wwii said, "it depends". If any of the collections were *always* best than the other, the slower ones probably wouldn't exist. Even the basic collections like `list`, `dict` and `set` each have got different upsides and downsides and are good for different purposes. You can check complexity of each operation here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity
If we compare, for example list and dict get and membership check:

Lists get is always O(1), so it's better than dict O(n) in worst-case scenario. On the other hand, dicts have O(1) average complexity for `x in c` operation, while for lists it's gonna be O(n).

So you have to analyse how you use each of your collections, what data it holds etc. to really be able to tell what data structure fits your needs best.

That being said, there is a famous quote: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092) - do you really **need** that performance increase? Is it worth potentially breaking something due to different quirks of each type?